# How to migrate kubernetes config in new spring boot 2.4

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kubernetes

I follow [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-kubernetes/docs/current/reference/html/index.html#configmap-propertysource) example to load more config maps in kubernetes so I create bootstrap.properties in my project. However bootstrap is now no more supported in spring boot 2.4 but I can not find how should I replace this in [doc](https://spring.io/blog/2020/08/14/config-file-processing-in-spring-boot-2-4)

Now my properties looks like:

bootstrap:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: @appname@
  cloud:
    kubernetes:
      config:
        sources:
          - name: "@appname@"
          - name: "@appname@-db"
      reload:
        enabled: true
```

and application-kubernetes:

```
spring:
  mvc:
    servlet:
      path: /mypath/
server:
  servlet:
    context-path: "@default.context.path@"
  port: 8080

management:
  server.port: 8081
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: "*"
  endpoint:
    health:
      probes:
        enabled: true
    shutdown:
      enabled:
        true
  metrics:
    export:
      prometheus.enabled: true
  health:
    livenessstate:
      enabled: true
    readinessstate:
      enabled: true
```

What is the right way to catch new spring boot features ?

**UPDATE**

[here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-kubernetes/issues/340) I found another link that config source can not by in application properties